# Segmentation fault when calling function recursively

Tags: c, function, recursion, segmentation-fault

My task is to create a function which should calculate the arcsin for my input.

I tried to debug it using xcode. Everything works fine until return `arcsin(new);` is called. Then it's a `segmentation fault: 11`. I am not sure why but breakpoint at `float arcsin(floatvalue){ ... }`while running second cycle tells me that float old and float value is `NAN`.

```
float arcsin(float value){

     float old = value;
     float new = value + (0.5 * ((value * value * value)/3));
     float accurate = 0.00001;  

     if ((new - old) < accurate){
        return new;
     }

     else{
        return arcsin(new);
     }
}


int function_arcsin(int sigdig, float value){

    value = arcsin(value);
    printf("%.10e\n",value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: new is a reserved keyword. Call it something like float newval

Comment: @spicavigo: That's C, not C++, so it's fine.

Comment: @spicavigo: are you sure in C is a reserved keyword?

Comment: @rojcyk: please could you add also where that function is called? Is inside a cycle? please add some details.

Comment: @rojcyk: Is there any particular reason you implemented `arcsin` recursively. This can (and should) be done iteratively, unless you're gambling whether the compiler might straighten out your tail recursion.

Comment: maybe your formula is wrong? it's dying on 174510th call to itself on my machine.

Comment: @spicavigo I tried to rename it, but its still a segmentation fault.

Comment: @all, my apologies. I didn't read the entire thing.

Comment: @bitmask No there isn't. I thought this is the correct way how to do this. But I will look more into iterations. Thanks.

Comment: @rojcyk - the variable name won't affect the behaviour in C - it's a C++ keyword, not a C keyword. I don't know whether it's bad style to use C++ reserved words as identifiers in C - my guess is only if the project is multi-language.

Comment: @rojcyk - is this homework? Also, have you been given the approximation method to use, and can you include an English description in the question?

Comment: @Steve314 Yes it is a homework. And its description is 4x A4 pages long. This is just a small part of the project I don't have enough time to translate it unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A seg fault occurs when the call stack gets too big - i.e. too many levels of recursion.

In your case, this means the condition `(new - old) < accurate` will always evaluate to false - well, maybe not always, but enough times to bloat the call stack.

Testing your code I see that `new`(probably not a good variable name choice) keeps growing until it exceeds the limits of float. Your algorithm is probably wrong.

Comment: The name `new` threw me for a second too because it's a keyword in C++, but does that really count as a bad choice in C? (I'm not that familiar with C style rules these days).

Comment: @Steve314 you never know when you want to port or include your code to C++, might as well choose well now instead of refactoring later, right?

Comment: @Steve314 such uninformative variable names as `new` or `old` should count as bad choice at any language actually

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Thanks for the feedback, I will work on my variable names. I will also look into the algorithm too. Once again, thanks!

Comment: @maksenov - I agree to a point, but this is a very small function and in context the meaning is clear. Even the meaning of `value` (less specific than `old` or `new`) is probably OK in context. My habit for an obvious-what-it-is solitary parameter like this is to call it `p`. I agree that it's good to get into good habits early, and it's probably easier to break a habit of unnecessarily long and explicit names than it is to break a habit of too-short and unclear names, so you're probably right from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the segmentation fault is caused by too-deep recursion. Although many compilers can optimise a lot of recursive code into iterative code, some can't, and it's quite common with e.g. debug options to disable this.

Conversion to an iterative form would stop the segfault - but, unless I miss my guess, give an infinite loop instead. I wouldn't expect a *working* recursive solution to be a problem here, unless you were testing with values out of the range the approximation converges with - in this case, my first guess is that inputs in the range -pi to +pi should be OK for any usable arcsin approximation.

I'm not familiar with the iterative approximation of arcsin, and my google-fu hasn't turned up the answer yet, but I suspect you have the calculation in the `float new = ...` line wrong.

I found this link...

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907214220/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54319.html)

It's not that helpful - your code isn't suggestive of either approach described.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your program and saw that never ends looping:

```
((new - old) < accurate)  // never is true
```

if you try with numbers > 0, reaches nan in 10 iterations. With numbers < 0, continue for thousands of times and causes too-deep recursion.